# Wrong result in list comprehension codition

Tags: python, django

I am getting wrong result in my list comprehension if  condition . I tried everything any hints what could be wrong.

```
po_list = [n for n in Material.objects.all() 
    if (((F('n.total_inventory') + F('n.total_po') - F('n.total_so'))) < F('n.min_quantity'))]
```

Currently it will always give all the data of the Material model 
If I switch the greater/smaller sign  directions it gives no data

---

EDIT
I wrongly assumed it is self explanatory the code .
The right result is to get on the output only the values from Material that will satisfy this condition calculation  of those 3 properties ((F('n.total_inventory') + F('n.total_po') - F('n.total_so')) will be smaller than F('n.min_quantity') only those rows should  be listed in po_list

This code is part of Django project and F in django framework is :
An F() object represents the value of a model field. It makes it possible to refer to model field values and perform database operations using them without actually having to pull them out of the database into Python memory.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/queries/

I cant just filter by those values since they are calculated properties.

Comment: You realize you have not explained what the *right* result is, much less why it is right, don't you?

Comment: What is `F`, and why are you passing it strings? It doesn't look like your condition uses `n` in any way.

Comment: indeed the condition is independent of the variable `n`

Comment: Ok Thanks , that's explains it , How to make it dependant in my case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the `F` objects and use the `n` variable:

```
po_list = [n for n in Material.objects.all() 
           if (n.total_inventory + n.total_po - n.total_so) < n.min_quantity]
```

Comment: Cant do it. Since those 3 fields are calculated properties in the Model and I cant filter on those.

Comment: @JohnGoldman okay, updated the answer to reflect that. Hope that helps.